# Capybara page.execute_script stopped working

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I try to run my cucumber tests and for some reason the page.execute_script method stopped working. Its just not executing anymore. Anyone an idea why that is?

I have something like this in my step: page.execute_script("$('#itinerary_start_date').removeAttr('readonly')")

Comment: Your question needs more information. What driver are you using with Capybara? Can you tell whether there is a Javascript error in the page?

Comment: I'm using poltergeist and there are no js errors